# Is there a way a website can accurately determine the source domain that reached it?

Tags: web, single-sign-on

I have a website where I click on a link and am redirected to another website.
Is there a way, the other website (www.otherwebsite.com) can determine accurately that the request has been sent from my website www.mywebsite.com?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer here you go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using the HTTP header called "[Referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer)" (no, that is not a spelling mistake, that is actually the name of the header).

For instance, in [PHP](http://php.net/) you would do this:

```
<?php echo "You came from this site: <b>".htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])."</b>";
```

The same code in JavaScript:

```
document.write("You came from this site: <b>"+document.referrer+"</b>");
```

This could output:

> You came from this site: **http://www.mywebsite.com/index.html**

Comment: Strictly speaking, it *is* a spelling mistake, but it's *their mistake*, not yours =) +1

Comment: I wish I could select more than one answer StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

what language?

with javascript you can use : document.referrer
with php you can use  : $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

however, there is NO method in any language that is 100% accurate, do to the ability to spoof headers.